# Reservation message in django

Tags: python, django

I am making a chatbot using a messenger called KakaoTalk.

I wrote a function that sends a message when the current request is received.

However, I can not implement the function of sending notification characters in the morning.

I need your help.

Here is my code sample.

```
def message(request):

    json_str = ((request.body).decode('utf-8'))
    received_json_data = json.loads(json_str)
    content = received_json_data['content']

    data_will_be_send = {
            'message': {
             'text': connect_apiai.get_apiai(papago.get_papago(content))
            }
    }

    return JsonResponse(data_will_be_send)
```

How can I send JsonResponse without a request?

Comment: Can we assume that you're currently getting error messages? What are they? Is your actual code indented? if not, I don't see how this will run at all.

Comment: This is indented. I'll make the code look better. The current common features are working well.

Comment: Error messages/ Stacktrace?

Comment: This code did not cause an error, but I wrote a basic code like this, and I do not know how to write a verbatim message code